# Skype Click To Call causing errors on websites

Tags: jquery, skype

If You are a web developer you may have come across one of the following errors
For Chrome:

> POST https://localhost:26143/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

or

> https://localhost:26143/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

And for Firefox:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
>
> Script: resource://gre/modules/commonj…skype_ff_extension/data/pnr.js:19

Or you have just found your website loads incredibly slow while you have the Skype click to call plugin installed, and may be wondering is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this answer to this for many has been to disable Skype Click To Call but this is not a valid solution for public websites as thousands of people have the plugin installed.

The actual solution is to disable it for your website so that when a member of the public loads your website it tell Skype not to run there plugin.

To do this just add the below code to the head of your website

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```

Comment: So you're basically saying : `If you're using this plugin on your website, don't use it.` ?

Comment: The plugin is installed on many clients browsers and it breaks many websites, this is to stop the client side plugin breaking your website because you have no control over what plugins/extentions/addons that clients have installed